# How to calculate numbers with loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, loops

I am working with javascript, i have static value(15000) and i want
15000*1.5/100+15000 with 90 times,i mean after getting result i want to again calculate that value(result/output,for example 225) 90 times,How can i do this ?

```
<script>
const cars ="15000";
for (let i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
   cars = cars*1.5/100+15000;
   cars --;
 }
 </script>
```

In c++ i did with following code but now i want to convert to javascript code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    float a,b,c;
    std::cin>>b;
    for(int i=0;i<90;i++)
    {
        a=b*1.5/100;
        c=a+b;
        std::cout<<c<<"\n";
        b=c;
    }
    std::cout << "Hello world!"<<c;

    return 0;
}
```

My expected output is

```
15000
15225
15453.4
15685.2
15920.5
16159.3
16401.6
...
```

Comment: If you want to be able to _change_ the value of `cars` - then you should not declare it as `const`.

Comment: Your C++ example uses three variables for this; so why are you trying to do this with only a single one now in your JS version?

Comment: @CBroe what is the solution ? can you update/write code so i can check

Comment: @CBroe c++ program is working fine you can check in c++ compiler, but i am new in javascript so i just tried not sure about output,Hope you understand,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
let cars = 15000;
for (let i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
  console.log(parseFloat(cars.toFixed(1))); // set 1 decimal and print it
  cars = (cars * 1.5) / 100 + cars; // same function as c++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an array and push the result into for each iteration of the loop, then use the [i] index to use the new value. Finally you just have to output the array and you already have all your data stored.

```js
let carsArray = [15000];

for (let i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
   cars = carsArray[i]*1.5/100 + carsArray[i];
   carsArray.push(cars);
 }
 
 console.log(carsArray);
```